# Thread creation error when using the useLibrary clause in gradle

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have an app compiled with sdk version 22, actually I needed to upgrade it to 23 to add new elements and features.

The problem: after upgraded it and solve dependency problems (httpclient is deprecated so I used useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy' as mentioned in doc) I am having this error just after app is launched:

```
03-14 18:10:53.788 1566-2303/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-12338
Process: com.my.app.debug, PID: 1566
java.lang.InternalError: Thread starting during runtime shutdown
at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.AbstractConnPool.enableConnectionGC(AbstractConnPool.java:145)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.createConnectionPool(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:125)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager.<init>(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:103)
at org.acra.util.HttpRequest.getHttpClient(HttpRequest.java:214)
at org.acra.util.HttpRequest.send(HttpRequest.java:141)
at org.acra.sender.HttpSender.send(HttpSender.java:225)
at org.acra.SendWorker.sendCrashReport(SendWorker.java:179)
at org.acra.SendWorker.checkAndSendReports(SendWorker.java:141)
at org.acra.SendWorker.run(SendWorker.java:77)
```

I have read that this problem is a reported bug in ACRA but in latest version is solved. How can I have this problem when using "uselibrary" and not when using sdkversion 22?

This is build.gradle before migration:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.github.ben-manes.versions'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'
        classpath 'com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.11.3'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/pixlui-1-0-5.jar')

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.androidmapsextensions:android-maps-extensions:2.2.0'

    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile ('ch.acra:acra:4.5.0'){
        exclude group: 'org.json'
    }
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.4'
    provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:15.0'
    compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.5.3'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'
    compile 'com.github.rahatarmanahmed:circularprogressview:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'

    compile 'com.github.hotchemi:android-rate:0.5.6'

    // Testing dependencies
    testCompile "junit:junit:4.5"
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5"

    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2'){
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.2'
}
```

This is after migrating build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.github.ben-manes.versions'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath 'com.github.ben-manes:gradle-versions-plugin:0.11.3'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/pixlui-1-0-5.jar')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.androidmapsextensions:android-maps-extensions:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.5'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
    compile ('ch.acra:acra:4.5.0'){
        exclude group: 'org.json'
    }
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.4'
    provided 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger-compiler:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:15.0'
    compile 'com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.5.3'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'
    compile 'com.github.rahatarmanahmed:circularprogressview:2.3.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.hotchemi:android-rate:0.5.6'

    testCompile "junit:junit:4.5"
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5"

    androidTestCompile ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2'){
        exclude module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.2'
}

android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    signingConfigs {
        blabla...
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'

        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'

        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
    }
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.my.app'
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        def STRING = "String"
        def TRUE = "true"
        def FALSE = "false"
        def URL_REQUEST = "URL_REQUEST"
        debug {
            blabla
        }
        release {
            blabla
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        full {
            blabla
        }
    }
}
```

I am new in Android, what I am doing wrong?